# css class override not working for just one specific class

Tags: css

In my Wordpress CSS I have added a few extra classes. Depending on screen widht I want to override these. This works fine, except for one class. I am at the end of my wits what could be the cause. Here's the code excerpt (class "field-space" is being successfully overriden, class "formflex" is not)

```
.formflex {
   display: flex;
   background-color:yellow;
}

.field-space {
   padding-right: 20px;
   background-color:lightgrey
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {

    .formflex {
       ! flex-direction : column;
     background-color:blue;
    }

.field-space {
    padding-right: 60px;
    background-color:green;
}
}
```

The background-color specification is there for testing whether things work. The color of elements with a field-space dev are changing, the ones for formflex are not. Am I missing some typo (checked a thousand times)?

Tested with Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: There's a syntax error in your CSS (extraneous `!` character).

Comment: Remove the ! at the beggining of flex-direction and add !important before ;, like this:
flex-direction : column !important;

Comment: @Dave111 The `!important` isn’t necessary at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/important

> A ! delimiter followed by the important keyword marks the declaration
> as important. The !important flag alters the rules selecting
> declarations inside the cascade. A declaration that is not important
> is called normal.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

> Specificity is the algorithm used by browsers to determine the CSS
> declaration that is the most relevant to an element, which in turn,
> determines the property value to apply to the element. The specificity
> algorithm calculates the weight of a CSS selector to determine which
> rule from competing CSS declarations gets applied to an element.

Just to make it clear because your words showed some confusion, you are overriding the specificity of a single css attribute and not the whole class. Those are ruleset applied to elements responding to a given selector. By the way you were doing it wrong...

...and since here you don't need to override any specificity, the `!important` clause is not needed.

As a side note, `.field-space` element needs the `height` set when displayed vertically.

```css
.formflex {
  display: flex;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.field-space {
  padding-right: 20px;
  background-color: lightgrey
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .formflex {
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: blue;
  }
  .field-space {
    padding-right: 60px;
    background-color: green;
    line-height: 1em;
    height: 1em;
  }
}

.formflex > *:not(.field-space){
  border: solid 1px gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="formflex">
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
  <div class="field-space"></div>
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
</div>
```